# Looking for name of short story - boy who saves the earth from alien invasion

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, alien-invasion

A short story from the 60s or 70s (I think) - a boy who meets invading aliens and saves the earth by telling them about the powers of his idol, a television superhero (he belongs to a fan club).  Passes the infallible lie-detection of the aliens because he *really* believes in the hero. They leave fearing certain defeat.  Earth is saved, but no one knows how close they came to being conquered by aliens.